# Stewart's Calculus (6 edn 2007) : p. 1097. §16.8, Exercise #4.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integral-domain

Source: Stewart. [*Calculus: Early Transcendentals* (6 edn 2007)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0495011665). p. 1097. §16.8, Exercise #4.

> Use Stokes' Theorem to evaluate $\int \int_S curl \ \vec F \cdot d \vec S $
>
> $4. \; F(x,y,z) = x^2 \ y^3\ z \ \vec i + \sin(x\ y\ z)\  \vec j + x\ y\ z\  \vec k$,
> $S$ is the part of the cone $y^2 =x^2 + z^2$ that lies between the planes $y = 0$ and $y = 3$, oriented in the direction of the positive $y$-axis.

I calculated $ curl \ \vec F $ :
$$ curl \ \vec F = ( xz-xy \cos(xyz) \ , \ -yz+x^2y^3 \ , \ yz \cos(xyz)-3x^2y^2z ) $$
Now I have to evaluate the domain $S$, and I have no idea how. I have a lot of difficulties to find a domain, and when I should use $\int \int_S curl \ \vec F \cdot d \vec S $ or $\int_c \vec F \cdot d \vec r $, because I always have difficulties on how to evaluate the domain of integration.

Comment: by rot you mean curl right ?

Comment: yes, sorry I will edit

Comment: The idea is that you compute the line integral rather than the surface one. What you have to notice is that the boundary of the cone is pretty easy: it's just a circle.

Comment: @Fantini what happen if I have a cone cutted by two planes ? let say $y=2$ and $y=3$

Comment: Then you cannot use Stokes' Theorem.

Comment: I think you are still able to use Stokes' Theorem, but you'll have two boundaries instead of one. You'd have two circles, one at $y=3$ and another at $y=2$. They'd have different radius also.

Comment: @ChrisK could you explain why ? how can I show that ?

Comment: @bobthemightyspellcaster, you can in fact use Stokes' Theorem (I was mistaken); basically you add the two line integrals, but because of opposite orientations, you should subract the counterclockwise integral at $y=2$ from the counterclockwise integral at $y=3$. Thank you, Bob! I had never actually thought about this before and I was (perhaps understandably) a bit perplexed.

Comment: @ChrisK Fantini should be thx for that

Comment: @Fantini in the case of two circles do I have to simply sum the two integrals ? (looks beyond my current math course)

Comment: @bobthemightyspellcaster, you actually have to subtract them; it has to do with the orientation of the manifold. I refer you to Analysis on Manifolds by Munkres.

Comment: @ChrisK yeah, actualy when I said sum I didn't take care of the orientation of the boundary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Fantini points out, the boundary is a circle - we have a winner - of radius $3$.

Then, we fix $y=3$ and parameterise $(x,z) = (\sqrt{9-z^2},z)$ and then integrate from $z=3$ to $z=-3$ (going counterclockwise). One must also note that by the Implicit Function Theorem, there no unique function $x(z)$ in an open neighbourhood of $(x,y,z) = (0,3,3)$ or $(x,y,z)=(0,3,-3)$ and so we must also integrate from $z=-3$ to $z=3$ with the parameterisation $(x,z) = (-\sqrt{9-z^2},z)$. Now $dx = z/\sqrt{9-z^2}\; dz$ in the first case (opposite sign in the second).

Note that the $y$-component vanishes and so we are left with $\oint_{P} (27x^2z,3xz)\cdot (dx, dz) = - \int_{-3}^{3} (27z^2\sqrt{9-z^2}+3z\sqrt{9-z^2}) dz + \int_{-3}^{3} (-27z^2\sqrt{9-z^2}-3z\sqrt{9-z^2}) dz = -54 \int_{-3}^{3} z^2\sqrt{9-z^2} dz.$

So the problem reduces to (letting $u = \sqrt{9 - z^2}$):

$-54 \int_{-3}^{3} z^2\sqrt{9-z^2} dz = -108 \int_{0}^{3} u(9-u^2)\cdot \frac{-u}{\sqrt{9-u^2}} du = -108\cdot \frac{-81\pi}{16} = \frac{3^7 \pi}{4}.$

Comment: I didn't check yet, but I guess with $(r,\theta,z)$ it would be easier to evaluate the integral.

Comment: how did you know that you have to integrate from from $0$ to $|3|$ did you just check the domain of existence of $\sqrt{9-z^2}$ ?

Comment: Yes, cylindrical coordinates would be better; as for $0$ to $3$, I used the fact that the function was even. The substitution can't be done otherwise (the function is not $C^1$ on the domain $[-3,3]$).

Comment: your explanations, and how you wrote your answer is really helpful for me. Maybe it's just a detail for common people, but writting "we fix $y=3$ and parameterise $(x,z)=(\sqrt{9-z^2},z)$" was what I needed to read. and using cartesians instead of polar-z show me another way (some times polars can shut too quickly some difficulties) and reminds me that a circle in cartesian is two pieces of functions...

Comment: Thanks. That's usually how I think about this kind of problem myself; so, perhaps, it is natural that this is how I write explanations as well.